# Launch calendar from system tray

Tags: 16.04, unity, indicator, panel, calendar

Is it possible to launch the calendar application by clicking on the date in the top-right of the screen in system tray, or from any items in its drop down menu?

I'm referring to the default calendar application of Ubuntu (Unity).

For more clarity i mean open calendar by clicking
here:

[image]

Comment: @JacobVlijm: `gnome-calendar` is default in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson AHA, I totally missed that. Never seen it, sincve I use the thunderbird plugin :)

Comment: AFAIK you can't launch [Calendar](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/clock-calendar.html) from the clock menu. But appointments in _Calendar_ will be shown in the clock.

Comment: Ah, I misread the question, indeed *from* the clock menu is an operation that would need breaking in the code. Is an additional icon in the panel an option?

Comment: While @JacobVlijm may have some idea, it may be worth mentioning that _Evolution_ has the kind of integration you ask for, i.e. you can open it from the clock menu. OTOH, _Evolution_ if kind of 'heavy' and takes a few seconds to launch.

Comment: Hi Graffio, posted. Please mention if all is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, adding `gnome-calendar` to the *existing* **Time & Date** menu would require breaking into the code. Apart from the fact that that seems to be out of the scope of AU, on the first update you'd need to to the same routine again.

#### Alternatively

Run the indicator below. It will add an icon to the panel for quick access to the calendar:

[image]

#### The code

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import signal
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
from gi.repository import Gtk, AppIndicator3
import subprocess

class Indicator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = 'test123'
        iconpath = "org.gnome.Calendar"
        self.indicator = AppIndicator3.Indicator.new(
            self.app, iconpath,
            AppIndicator3.IndicatorCategory.OTHER)
        self.indicator.set_status(AppIndicator3.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)       
        self.indicator.set_menu(self.create_menu())

    def create_menu(self):
        menu = Gtk.Menu()
        open_cal = Gtk.MenuItem('Show Calendar')
        open_cal.connect('activate', self.run_cal)
        menu.append(open_cal)
        # separator
        menu_sep = Gtk.SeparatorMenuItem()
        menu.append(menu_sep)
        # quit
        item_quit = Gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
        item_quit.connect('activate', self.stop)
        menu.append(item_quit)
        menu.show_all()
        return menu

    def run_cal(self, source):
        subprocess.Popen("gnome-calendar")

    def stop(self, source):
        Gtk.main_quit()

Indicator()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
Gtk.main()
```

#### How to use

1. Not sure if python3-gi is installed by default, but to make sure:

   ```
   sudo apt install python3-gi
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `indicator_runcal.py`
3. Test- run it with the command

   ```
   python3 /path/to/indicator_runcal.py
   ```

   A pnale icon should be added as in the image, choose <kbd>Show Calendar</kbd> from its menu.
4. If all works fine, add to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && python3 /path/to/indicator_runcal.py"
   ```

#### Additionally

You can give it a launcher:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=python3 /absolute/path/to/indicator_runcal.py
Name=Show Calendar
Type=Application
Icon=org.gnome.Calendar
```

1. Copy the code above into an empty file, save it as `cal_indicator.desktop`
2. Replace the path in `/absolute/path/to/indicator_runcal.py` by the real (and full, don't use `~` or `$HOME`) path to the script.
3. Move or copy the file to `~/.local/share/applications`, log out and back in.

   Now the indicator can be started from Dash:

   [image]

Comment: It works. Though it's not exactly what I looking for, it's the nearest solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Graffio31 I totally agree. The nicest would be to include it in the existing menu.